# htaccess file, user login and server access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, local

I'm trying to use a .htaccess file to block access to a web server directory (including sub directories) unless a user logs in OR the the hosting server is trying to access a file.

To be more clear, the protected directory is a admin directory for a website.
In that directory there are files that are called by the server the site is hosted on, through http.

The server is running Apache 2.2.24.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /..fakepath../.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
Satisfy Any
```

It works for the user to login but the server can not access files.
I'm thinking that maybe I can not reference to the server as localhost?

Comment: Instead of localhost provide hosting provider's external IP.

Comment: It does work with the external IP address.
It would be nice to have a more solid solution if the provider change the IP of the server or something.

Comment: Usually hosting co. has static IP so it shouldn't happen very often. You can also host their host name instead of IP and that won't change.